# Emacs interactive command getting "wrong number of arguments"

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have this function in my `.emacs` file that I thought used to work properly but now doesn't:

```
(defun insert-date ()
  (interactive "i")
  (insert (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")))
```

Emacs gives the error when I issue `M-x insert-date`:

```
call-interactively: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda nil (interactive "i") (insert (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d"))), 1
```

I thought the `i` argument to `interactive` tells Emacs to ignore any arguments because none are expected. What is wrong with the command that prevents me from using it like I think it should be used?

Answer (score 3):

The *texinfo* documentation says:

> Just `(interactive)' means pass no args when calling interactively.

You are perhaps confusing an argument that is always nil with no arguments at all.  The parameter `i` would be useful in cases where you want to ignore a particular parameter interactively, passing `nil` in that case.

There is also more information in the emacs manual: [20.2.1 Using interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html)

Comment: IOW, `"i"` expects an argument, and the function does not expect/provide one.

Comment: If you had a function that took three arguments but you only wanted to prompt for two interactively, it would be one way of ignoring the third argument wherever is was in the parameter list.